# Sending sms via GSM SIM800l module and stm32

Tags: sms, stm32, gsm, sim800l

I am trying to use gsm module with stm32 to send sms. Which gsm library should I use?
How can I write a simple code for sending sms via sim800l module ? Or is there a simple working example of this project? Can you suggest something working?

Comment: You would need to provide much more information about your specific requirements, the current state of your project, and the efforts you have already made yourself to answer this question - before you can reasonably expect anyone here to even attempt to help you.

Comment: For a pure software recommendation, there is this site too: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. I don't know much about it though.

Comment: How can I write a simple code for sending sms via sim800l module ? Or is there a simple working example of this project? Can you suggest something working?